# Object Expected error in Non Edit Mode only

Tags: error, jquery, spservices, updatelistitems

I have an issue with Javascript errors (Object Expected) in normal mode while it works in Edit mode. Its failing on the last line shown below.

```
$(document).ready(function() { updateListItem(); });

function updateListItem() {

var siteUrl = ‘/sites2/sppwgrqy/DashboardTest/’; alert(‘now to get siteUrl’ + siteUrl );

var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl ); //fails here
```

No hidden components. works fine in Edit mode. 
I upgraded to jquery 1.8.3 and then 1.9.0 with no change.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, if it works,

```
$(document).ready(function() { updateListItem(); });

function updateListItem() {

var siteUrl = ‘/sites2/sppwgrqy/DashboardTest’; 

var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl );
```

Not sure what's "sppwgrqy" and "DashboardTest" are but format should be something like this `'/sites/MySiteCollection';` according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh185011%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Hope it helps.

Comment: ‘/sites2/sppwgrqy/DashboardTest' is simply the Sharepoint Site.   Admins have not made SP Designer available to us, Therefore I am usign a CEWP to place this code.

Comment: I see, the problem is while getting ClientContext using Site URL, can you try var siteUrl = ‘/DashboardTest’;  and see if it makes any difference :)

Comment: I have tried changing the siteURL value.  It only works in Edit mode as is.  Needs a solution that deals with why it works only while in edit mode.